# Подскажите как правильно редактировать шаблон в OpenCart?

Tags: opencart

В OpenCart 3 не применяются изменения в шаблоне при редактировании через FTP.
Кеш выключен, хотя через админку шаблон редактируется все нормально, но как только очищаю кеш модификаторов верстка полностью вся слетает, и приходится восстанавливать сайт из резервной копии.

Шаблон чистый, недавно был куплен, cms также чистая, с нуля установленная.

Подскажите как правильно редактировать шаблон в этой CMS?

Answer (score 1):

Если залить отредактированный шаблон по фтп затем в **админка-дизайн-редактор шаблонов-нужный шаблон** нажать "**сбросить**" и затем "**сохранить**" потом **почистить кэш браузера** и *изменений нет*, то обратиться к автору шаблона, а вообще не покупать noname шаблоны, а редактировать дефолтный под свои нужды.